# How to pass intent from Adapter class to other activity but my variable is in other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have a problem. I want to pass my intent String "EmailHolder" from "WarehouseActivity" to "ProfilWarehouseActivity" by click on a recyclerview item in my Adapter Class which is named as "WarehouseAdapter". I want to pass the EmailHolder to fill my data when the user updates data inside ProfilWarehouseActivity.

Here is the "Intent" from my "WarehouseActivity" class :

```
 private String EmailHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_warehouse);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        EmailHolder = extras.getString("emailuser");
```

Here is how I make intent in Adapter Class "WarehouseAdapter" to pass ID data into "ProfilWarehouseActivity" :

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WarehouseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.namaitem.setText(listItems.get(position).get(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.TAG_WAREHOUSENAMA));
        holder.stockitem.setText("Stock : "+listItems.get(position).get(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.TAG_WAREHOUSESTOCK));
        holder.merekitem.setText("Merek : "+listItems.get(position).get(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.TAG_WAREHOUSEMEREK));
        holder.tglin.setText("Tanggal Masuk : "+listItems.get(position).get(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.TAG_WAREHOUSETGLIN));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ) {
                String idItem = listItems.get(position).get(Konfigurasi.TAG_ITEMID);

                passid(idItem);
            }
        });
    }

    private void passid(String idItem) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfilWarehouseActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.WAREHOUSE_ID,idItem);

        //i think this is for get my EmailHolder from WarehouseActivity to pass it with Intent from this Adapter class

        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

My question is How to pass Intent with a string "EmailHolder" that contain Intent value through my WarehouseAdapter (Adapter class), but "EmailHolder" is from my WarehouseActivity?

EDIT : Here is how i used the Adapter class from my WarehouseActivity

```
            final WarehouseAdapter mAdapter = new WarehouseAdapter( WarehouseActivity.this,list);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(WarehouseActivity.this));
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you used to instantiate the WarehouseAdapter in WarehouseActivity ?

Comment: Pass the emailHolder value to your Adapter while creating your Adapter constructor.

Comment: @Zain sure.. i will edit it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have couple of options to solve this:

**Option 1:**

If you want to start "ProfilWarehouseActivity" activity from the adapter, then you need to pass the "EmailHolder" from "WarehouseActivity" to your adapter by either its constructor, or a setter:

**Passing String into Adapter Constructor**

`final WarehouseAdapter mAdapter = new WarehouseAdapter( WarehouseActivity.this, list, EmailHolder);`

**Passing String using a Setter**

In "ProfilWarehouseActivity" activity:

`mAdapter.setEmailHolder(EmailHolder);`

In WarehouseAdapter adapter:

```
private String mEmailHolder;
public void setEmailHolder(String emailHolder) {
    this.mEmailHolder = emailHolder;
}

....

private void passid(String idItem) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfilWarehouseActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.WAREHOUSE_ID, idItem);
    intent.putExtra("EmailHolder", mEmailHolder);

    //i think this is for get my EmailHolder from WarehouseActivity to pass it with Intent from this Adapter class

    context.startActivity(intent);

}
```

**Option 2:**

The other option is to create a listener and implement it in "ProfilWarehouseActivity",  And pass the itemId as a parameter to the listener callback. Then let your "ProfilWarehouseActivity" call the "WarehouseActivity" instead of the WarehouseAdapter whenever this listener is triggered.

In WarehouseAdapter adapter:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int idItem);
}

ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener listener) {
    mItemClickListener = listener;
}

private void passid(String idItem) {
    if (mItemClickListener != null)
        mItemClickListener.onItemClick(idItem);
}
```

In "ProfilWarehouseActivity" activity:

```
class ProfilWarehouseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WarehouseAdapter.ItemClickListener { 
    private String EmailHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_warehouse);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        EmailHolder = extras.getString("emailuser");

    }

    @Override
    onItemClick(int itemId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfilWarehouseActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.WAREHOUSE_ID, idItem);
        intent.putExtra("EmailHolder", EmailHolder);
        startActivity(intent);        
    }   
    ... 

    final WarehouseAdapter mAdapter = new WarehouseAdapter( WarehouseActivity.this,list);
    mAdapter.setItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Perfect Solution. :)

Comment: can i receive intent in "ProfilWarehouseActivity" with any other intent function like using "Bundle extra"-"extra.getString" with Option 1...?

Comment: @DiooB yes you can use `intent.getStringExtra("EmailHolder");`

Comment: thank you.. it's working perfectly with a complete explanation.. it's like the answer before, but i think it's the best explanation..

Answer (score 2):

Pass the emailHolder value to your Adapter while creating your Adapter constructor. If I am not wrong, you might be calling the Adapater from your Activity, so just pass the value as constructor parameter.

```
wareHouseAdapter = new new WarehouseAdapter( WarehouseActivity.this,list,EmailHolder);
```

And in the `WarehouseAdapter`

```
WarehouseAdapter(otherparameter,String emailHolder) {

    this.emailHolder= emailHolder;
}
```

And on clicking the recyclerView item

```
 private void passid(String idItem) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfilWarehouseActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.WAREHOUSE_ID,idItem);

    //i think this is for get my EmailHolder from WarehouseActivity to pass it with Intent from this Adapter class

   intent.putExtra("emailHolder",emailHolder);


    context.startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. this is looks simple.. where do i put 

`wareHouseAdapter = new new WarehouseAdapter( WarehouseActivity.this,list,EmailHolder);`

Comment: EDIT : Here is how i used the Adapter class from my WarehouseActivity. Check this line of your edited question portion. `final WarehouseAdapter mAdapter = new WarehouseAdapter( WarehouseActivity.this,list,EmailHolder);` here you need to make the change.

Comment: oh okay.. i just need to put "EmailHolder" inside, beside "list"... i'll try it..

Answer (score 0):

i think i accidently found the answer (inspired from the other answer before me, thank you)... i just need to set String "EmailHolder" in "WarehouseActivity" to "public static" :

```
 public static String EmailHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_warehouse);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewItemWar);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        EmailHolder = extras.getString("emailuser");
```

And then use intent from "WarehouseAdapter" like this :

```
 private void passid(String idItem) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfilWarehouseActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Konfigurasi_Warehouse.WAREHOUSE_ID,idItem);


        intent.putExtra("emailuser",WarehouseActivity.EmailHolder); //i add this


        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

is it fine to change String from "private" to "public static"..?

Answer (score 0):

**For that you have use "interface " You cant directly pass value in Constructor also.**

Comment: Here the communication is not happening from adapter to the calling parent activity to make use of Interface.